# How to check in a ::whereHas query for a certain column value? Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

My query has a model "Token" that belongsToMany "App". The model "App" also belongsToMany "Token". Both are connected through a model "AppToken" with a belongsTo "App/Token".

I have a working query that gets me all token that have an app connected. I check the token for active and i need to check if the app is active as well. I'm confused about the query for that. I tried many stuff already, as an example of what i want to achieve, i wrote a not working example code so it's more clear what i mean.

Current query:

```
$result = Token::whereHas('app')->where('active', 1)->get();
```

The results are all "active" token that have at least one "active or inactive" app connected.

But i need all "active" token that have at least one "active" app connected. (not working example):

```
$result = Token::whereHas('app')->where('tokens.active', 1)->where('apps.active', 1)->get();
```

My models:
Token.php

```
public function app()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(App::class, 'app_tokens');
}
```

App.php

```
public function tokenlist()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Token::class, 'app_tokens', 'app_id', 'token_id');
}
```

AppToken.php

```
protected $fillable = [
    'app_id', 'token_id',
];

/**
 * Get the app record associated with the app_id.
 */
public function app()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(App::class);
}

/**
 * Get the token record associated with the token_id.
 */
public function tokenlist()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Token::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the answer to my question :)

```
$result = Token::whereHas('app',function ($q){
                    $q->where('active', 1);
            })->where('active', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of whereHas() you can try with with() method. It will work for me.
The example is written below.

App/Token.php

```
public function app(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\App’)->where(‘active’,1);    
}
```

App/App.php

```
public function token(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Token’); 
}
```

Query:-

1)If the cap is your column name in the tokens table then you can use orderBy() like this.

```
$result = Token::with(‘app')->where('active',1)->orderBy(‘cap')->get();
```

Or

2)If not then use only get().

```
$result = Token::with(‘app')->where('active',1)->get();
```

Comment: I think you are confused with my models. I added them to my initial post. The cap doesn't matter in this query problem. I can not use "with" because i need to filter all token that have no app connected. I only want those token "whereHas" apps connected in the AppToken table. And i need to check where the token is active and where the app is active. Those are 2 different col, each one active col in those 2 tables.